# iframe not updated when link is clicked

Tags: html, iframe

I am using Notepad++ and Chrome and Firefox to work with this code.
On page load (in both Chrome and Firefox) the frame is populated with 
the correct source (The Inkwell.net)

The challenge I have is two-fold. 
1) When I click on the link 
"WordPress", the frame contents should update to the WordPress site, but
it doesn't. All I get is a blank frame. I can reload the page and The 
Inkwell again populates the frame. That is, except in Firefox where

2)The frame stays blank even if I reload the page. I have to close out 
Firefox and reopen it for the frame to appear as it should.

I've tried using the "ID" tag as well and get nothing.

What am I missing? Please, any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

```css
    .myiframe {         
     display: block;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 0;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="myiframe">
     <iframe src="https://theinkwell.net" name="iframe-a" 
    width="50%" height="350"></iframe>
     <p><a href="https://wordpress.com/" target="iframe-a">WordPress</a></p>
    </div>
```

Here is a link to the page so you can see what is happening.

https://theinkwell.net/testing/iframe_conundrum.html

Comment: Thank you, Sphinx, for the edit. I will remember the order of ops for future use.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. I named the iframe "iframe-a" for simple use. I also gave it an id attribute and that did not work either. Can you 'show' me what you mean?

Comment: I found the root cause, for security policy, the action is rejected due to `Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://wordpress.com/ does not permit cross-origin framing.` You can open your web console, then will see this error when click '<a>'.

Comment: Thanks Sphinx. I did not think of that. I know Google doesn't allow linking into an iframe but I didn't think Wordpress did. I will change the page and see what happens. Thanks bunches.

Comment: It didn't work. And I changed the name of the frame to "thisiframe" just in case and it just isn't working. Not in Firefox or Google Chrome.

Comment: [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options), When you access wordpress.com, you will see X-Frame-Option=**sameorigin** in the response from wordpress. This field is set by wordpress not google.

Comment: I am finding that many many sites are doing this. I have not found a site to load into an iframe. As for the Firefox issue of not loading the inkwell until after closing and reopening the browser - well the console told me that the SSL certificate was untrusted and would therefore be restricted. 

I am starting to wonder why I should even worry about iframes.

Comment: I finally found a site that will open in the iframe. Now I can relax and know that it was nothing in my code!  THANK YOU SPHINX for ALL your help!

Comment: Hey @rocknriter, it's none of that is needed. Go back to that site and fix your link: `"https://www.writeoutloud.net/competitions/wolf18"` **"There's an extra double quote in the url**. After removing that extra double quote the iframe's src changes as expected in Chrome and Firefox. It looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/98Qy6XD.png

Comment: Thanks, zer00ne! I keep missing the details. :P